# Which term of the binomial expansion of $\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{50}$ is the greatest?

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

> Which term of the binomial expansion of $\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^{50}$ is the greatest?

How can I find it, without comparing all 51 values?

Is there a quicker way to do it? (The solution says it's the number at index 30)

Comment: Quite bad-worded this way, a number may be associated with many sequences. I'd rather ask "which term of the binomial expansion of $(1+\sqrt{2})^{50}$ is the greatest?" both in the title and in the question body.

Comment: Sorry, my English isn't that good, so translating exercises from Serbian is also rather a challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the expansion of $(1+p)^m$ which is given by
$$(1+p)^m=\sum_{r=0}^{m}\underbrace{{m\choose r  }p^r}_{u_r}$$

Note that 
$$u_{r+1}={m\choose r+1}p^{r+1}=\frac{m-r}{r+1}\color{blue}{{m\choose r}p^r}\cdot p=\left[\frac{m-r}{r+1}\cdot p\right]\color{blue}{u_r}$$
For $u_{r+1}<u_r$ (in order for $u_r$ to be the greatest term),
$$\frac{m-r}{r+1}\cdot p<1 \Rightarrow 
r>\frac{mp-1}{p+1}$$
Here $m=50, p=\sqrt2$, hence
$$r>28.8\Rightarrow r=29$$
i.e. the greatest term is the 30th term, as given by 
$$u_{29}={50\choose 29}(\sqrt2)^{29}$$

*NB - the first term corresponds to $u=0$*

Answer (score 9):

Compare every two consecutive terms by writing
$$\frac{T_{r+1}}{T_r}=\frac{\binom{50}{r}(\sqrt{2})^r}{\binom{50}{r-1}(\sqrt{2})^{r-1}}$$
And then see where this fraction is greater than 1 and where it is less than 1.

Comment: I guess fast enough, thanks :D